# How to get element ids of inflated xml in listview?

Tags: android

I have a custom listview.In that I want to get ids of widgets used in particular row.Because I want to set the values on a textview click ,which is present in same xml.

How to get element ids of particular row

thanks

Answer (score 0):

See answer at: [How to get widget ids of selected row of listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513596/how-to-get-widget-ids-of-selected-row-of-listview#comment18497991_13513596)

As you want to get hold of the textview in the same row, you can do the following.

with the textview that was clicked get its parent and then using the parentview you can search for your textview:

```
View parent = (View) textViewThatWasClicked.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            TextView textViewThatYouWantToChange = parent.findViewById(R.id.textViewThatYouWantToChange);
            textViewThatYouWantToChange.setText(...);
        }
```

you will need to change the id that you look for to the id you have for that other textview. If you need to set an id you can do this in the xml layout file you used.

I cant follow your code well enough to actually give you the code but this should be enough to get you in the right direction.

Comment: As we see in android facebook app,if we click like,then like-count is also gets updated i.e he is getting the id of like-count,similiar thing I want to do.I want to get like-count id on button click in a row

Comment: Show me the code you have got and i will show you how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511686/getting-listview-row-data (you can find my code here) thanks for reply