# How to get widget ids of selected row of listview

Tags: android, facebook, listview, textview

I am using an custom listview in my application.In my row I have (two images,remaining textviews).

when I click on one of textview,I want to set another textview data.I wrote the code below to do this

```
     likes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
//          if(likes.getText().toString().equals("Like")){
               TextView t=(TextView)v;
              TextView likesnumber1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.likesnumber);
//            TextView  likesnumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likesnumber);
                int i=  Integer.parseInt(likescount.get(position));

           if(like_or_ulike.get(position).equals("Like")){
                Log.e("inlike","like");
                like_or_ulike.set(position, "Unlike");
                t.setText(like_or_ulike.get(position));
                UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+objectid.get(position)+"/likes?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"post");
//             listView.getAdapter().getItemAt(position);
               j=i+1;
               String s=Integer.toString(j);
            likescount.set(position, s);
             likesnumber1.setText(likescount.get(position));

            }
            else{
                Log.e("unlike","unlike");
                like_or_ulike.set(position, "Like");
                t.setText(like_or_ulike.get(position));
                UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+objectid.get(position)+"/likes?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"DELETE");

                   j=i-1;
                 String s=Integer.toString(j);
                likescount.set(position, s);
                 likesnumber1.setText(likescount.get(position));
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I get the another textview id of particular row when I click the textview.Is it possible to get the ids of that particular row.

Comment: is the textview you want in the same row? or different?

Comment: I want the textview id of same row i.e likescount id when I click on like because I want to set the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to get hold of the textview in the same row, you can do the following.

with the textview that was clicked get its parent and then using the parentview you can search for your textview:

```
View parent = (View) textViewThatWasClicked.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            TextView textViewThatYouWantToChange = parent.findViewById(R.id.textViewThatYouWantToChange);
            textViewThatYouWantToChange.setText(...);
        }
```

you will need to change the id that you look for to the id you have for that other textview. If you need to set an id you can do this in the xml layout file you used.

I cant follow your code well enough to actually give you the code but this should be enough to get you in the right direction.

Comment: I just want to know,how the android facebook app is updating the likescount that instantly.Here I am just incrementing and decrementing values.Am I doing right?

Comment: If this is especially for facebook i recommend looking at the android facebook sdk https://developers.facebook.com/android/

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom layout for each row in listview then you can provide id for each of the View in your custom view and then set setOnItemClickListener for your listview and you'll be able to reach each row as a view.
When you have access to your row like a View then you can use view.findViewById and get all of your views from your custom view by their id.

Comment: But I want to get the viewids of row,not on itemclick .I want to get ids when I click textview in the rowview.

Comment: Then in getView of adapter you have an access to all of your views and you can setOnClickListener in getView and in this context you have access to all of the others views (BTW use ViewHolders in your lists).